# How do I open a url from <a> on default OS browser in Electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to take an to an external website, but I do not want it to happen inside electron, I want it to be in the default browser.

I've tried this code:

```
const {shell} = require('electron')
shell.openExternal('https://github.com')
```

Docs from here : [electron docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/shell.md#shellopenexternalurl)

But its does't work on Mac os (When id clicked the , its nothing happened...).

So... how can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try this? `require("shell").openExternal("http://www.google.com")`

Comment: Yes， I did, but its't work..  On MAC OS